# Vertex stuck when using mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, vertices, mirror

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to fix this. The vertices did not start out like this. but somewhere in the process this happened and I can't quite figure out where. I think it started when I added another edge loop. If you look at the center loop the to loops to the left and right of it are the edge loops I refer too. I'm using the mirror modifier for the sake of symmetry and overall easier modeling. I'm just trying to separate the two  vertices but they refuse. I've tried splitting, separating, even ripping. Nothing works. When I try to use the axis arrow to separate them nothing happens the don't move in any direction and I can't figure out why. Any and all help in this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Clipping option in the mirror modifier.

Comment: You have a single vertex selected. This happened when the verticies 'met' as you moved them and had clipping turned on. If you look you also have merge so those 2 verticies became one. Look at the information bar at the top - 1 vert selected

Comment: JEEZUS thnk you so much. I didn't even notice I did that. It's like second nature to do so now. thank you so much. that (after vigorous Ctrl+Z presses) actually fixed the issue thanks a ton guys